# Find a conservative vector field that has the indicated potential

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Find a conservative vector field that has the indicated potential$$f(x,y,z)=\sin \left (x^2+y^2+z^2\right ).$$My answer:$$2x\cos \left (x^2+y^2+z^2\right )i+2y\cos \left (x^2+y^2+z^2\right )j+2z\cos \left (x^2+y^2+z^2\right )k.$$For this question, do I need to derivate $x$ for $i$, $y$ for $j$, $z$ for $k$?

Answer (score 3):

A conservative vector field is the gradient of the potential,
$$
\left(
{\partial f\over\partial x},
{\partial f\over\partial y},
{\partial f\over\partial z}
\right)
$$
so your answer is correct up to formatting issues.